# Weird error when using python relating to pip, anaconda and kivy

Tags: python, pip, kivy, anaconda

This is what happens what I type python in my terminal. I can't understand why. I am using windows.

```
Abhishek@ABHISHEK ~ (master)
$ python
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 14:26:21) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>>
```

So far I tried reinstalling pip doesn't work. I am unable to uninstall kivy

```
Abhishek@ABHISHEK ~ (master)
$ python -m pip uninstall kivy
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in c:/Users/sony\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-03-31_10.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
     exec code in run_globals
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
     sys.exit(pip.main())
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 217, in main
     return command.main(cmd_args)
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 179, in main
     for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\logging\config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\logging\config.py", line 576, in configure
     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console_errors': 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'closed'
```

or check the list of packages installed:

```
$ pip list
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in c:/Users/sony\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-03-31_7.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
     sys.exit(pip.main())
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 217, in main
     return command.main(cmd_args)
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 179, in main
     for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\logging\config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\logging\config.py", line 576, in configure
     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console_errors': 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'closed'

Abhishek@ABHISHEK ~ (master)
$ python -m pip list
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.glew-0.1.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 2 of c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.12-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyError: 'kivy'

Remainder of file ignored
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in c:/Users/sony\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-03-31_8.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
     exec code in run_globals
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
     sys.exit(pip.main())
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 217, in main
     return command.main(cmd_args)
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 179, in main
     for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\logging\config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
   File "c:\Anaconda\lib\logging\config.py", line 576, in configure
     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console_errors': 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'closed'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the three links to python.org that you provided are missing. Can you include the code on your question?

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound please check again.

Comment: Post your code here please, don't just provide links to it

Comment: @GilbertAllen posted.